# Change a TextView with TextWatcher

Tags: android

My problem is as follows:

I have two textview. The first one is updated after user action and in the second, I want to store the value which was in the first textview before it is updated.
For this I'm using a textwatcher as follows :

```
   textview1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
             String X = textview1.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            textview2.setText(X);
        }
    });
```

But the second textview is not updated correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  textview1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 String x;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
           x  = charSequence.toString();
        }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        textview2.setText(x);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work :( When I check the value of X in beforeTextChanged, it contains the value of textview2 instead of textview1...

Comment: After some check, X contains a value different than textview1 and textview2. What should contain charsequence ? thanks

Comment: I understand, it contain a value I put in the xml file. But why charsequence is not updating with the new value of textview1 ?

Comment: `beforeTextChanged()` contains the old value. The other two have the new value. Suppose inside your xml, the textview had a text value"first". Then inside onCreate(), you are setting a TextChangeListener. After that, you call `textview1.setText("Second")`. Now `x="first"`. After that you set `textview1.setText("Third")`. Now `x="Second"`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In fact, charSequence keeps the first value of textview1 and it is not updating with new value. Consequently, textview2 has still the first value of textview1 even if it is updated...

Comment: TextView are in a fragment. Can I use the textwatcher in the fragment or I have to use it from the Activity ?

Comment: email me a smallest program, clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`X` is a local String within `beforeTextChanged`. so this X is not the same that you are using in `afterTextChanged`. Use a member variable instead.